# The left-hand-side of continuous assignment is illegal

Tags: verilog

My input consists of a parameterized number of units. The output I need is to remove the first bit of each unit.
For example if the input has units of size 3-bits each and the input value was `011011`, the output should be `1111`

Here is the solution i used for this:

```
parameter data_in_size = 11;
parameter data_out_size = 10;
parameter units = 4;
parameter skip_bits = 1;

input [data_in_size * units - 1 : 0] data_in;
output [data_in_size * units - 1 : 0] data_out;

genvar i;
generate
for (i = 0; i < units; i = i + 1) begin
    assign data_out[data_out_size * i +: data_out_size] = data_in [(data_in_size * i + skip_bits) +: data_out_size];

end
endgenerate
```

But I get the following error `The left-hand-side of continuous assignment is illegal`

How can i get through this error and why i am getting it ?

Comment: I don't see a problem (other than a type in the declaration of data_out).

Answer (score 2):

Your code works perfectly well. Might be a **simulator** **issue**.

But I would like to focus on **logic implementation** in your code. The logic seems to be wrong.

First error seems to be in **declaration** of `data_out` and the **slicing logic** : `data_in [(data_in_size * i + skip_bits) +: data_out_size]` must be **replaced** with: `data_in [(data_in_size * i + skip_bits) +: data_in_size]`

Lets suppose `i=0; data_out_size=3; data_in_size=4` then the LHS evaluates to `data_out[2:0] = data_in[4:1]`. When `i=1`, `data_out[5:3] = data_in[8:5]`. As you can see the bit slicing seems to be **incorrect**. Since **LSB** is sliced.

I think you might need to have following logic for **bit slicing**:

```
assign data_out[data_out_size * i +: data_out_size] = data_in[(data_in_size * i) +: (data_in_size - skip_bits)];
```

This will slice the **MSB** bit of every unit chunk, keeping the rest of bits as it is.

I simulated your code at [EdaPlayground here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/QNF). As an example, you will have following data_out and data_in values. Note the sliced MSB from each unit.

```
data_int = 1100101010010101
data_out = 100010001101
```